# Chart.js remove border from x/y Axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chart.js

I'm using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) for one of my projects. In which I want to remove border from x/y axis. Any help would be really helpful.  Refer Attached Image
[image]
Please not that I'm not referring to the GridLines(Which I already turned off using scaleShowGridLines : false)

**Chart Script**

```
var topVideos = {
    labels : ["","","","",""],
    datasets : [
      {
        fillColor : "rgba(2,137,203,1)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(2,137,203,0.8)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
        data : [90000, 200000, 70000, 100000, 180000 ]
      }
    ]

}
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = $("#topvideos").get(0).getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).HorizontalBar(topVideos, {
      responsive : true,
      barShowStroke: false,
      scaleShowGridLines : false,
      barValueSpacing : 7,
      barDatasetSpacing : 30,
    });
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using a fork of Chart.js and not the actual chart.js (since the current stable version doesn't have horizontal bars)

In Chart.js, you can set the scale line color to a transparent value, like so

```
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).HorizontalBar(topVideos, {
     scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
     ...
```

If the fork is from a version after this, the same options should work in your forked library as well.

Comment: Thanks. That option worked. I used an addon plugin - https://github.com/tomsouthall/Chart.HorizontalBar.js   with chart.js to get horizontal bars.

Answer (score 3):

options :  {

```
        scales: {

                yAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    drawBorder: false,

                }
            }]
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

In Chart.js 3.5.1 there is a `drawBorder` property which accepts boolean value. If true, the border is drawn at the edge between the axis and the chart area.

```
options: {
  scales: {
      x: {
        ...
        grid: {
          drawBorder: false,
        },
      },
      y: {
        ...
        grid: {
          drawBorder: false,
        },
      },
  },
}
```